# How to search for bounties awarded to my answers?

Tags: support, bounty

Is there a convenient way to search for answers of mine that have been awarded bounties?  I know that I can look through the "reputation" tab of my user profile, but this is very tedious, especially if I'm looking for a bounty from long ago.

Comment: Perhaps the title should be more specific "How to search for bounties that my answers have earned"? I thought you meant bounties to be earn

Comment: @veronika Good suggestion.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Activity tab of your user page, click on [Bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties) (in the string of buttons below the reputation graph and Newest/Next Badge information).  That string starts with Summary and ends with Votes, and Bounties falls just past the halfway mark.

In the Bounties mode you have three submodes (buttons to the right side of the desktop page), Active, Offered, and Earned.  Click on [Earned](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=earned) if you want to see the bounties your Answers have earned.

Comment: +1, a bit embarrassing that I've forgoten about this. I will add that if you want give to people reading this a direct link to their profile, you can use `users/current`. In this way you can link to [the bounties tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties) and [the earned bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=earned)

Comment: Thanks @Martin.  My slightly weird link-less exposition resulted from posting from my phone while looking at the Activity page on my desktop!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) query: [Answers by a specific user which received bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1377192/answers-by-a-specific-user-which-received-bounties?uid=253140). By changing the uid parameter you can check which user are you looking at.

Of course, you can refine the query using further criteria.

Keep in mind that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week.

Comment: +1 Although hardmath's answer is probably most appropriate to my original question, I do really like this one--I didn't even know about SEDE until this!