# Question about bounties and serial votes.

Tags: discussion, bounty, voting, serial-voting

1. Can I see the question that I put a bounty on (I am not the OP of that question) in the “bountied questions” list? I can’t seem to be able to see it and am freaking out, thinking it’s not getting viewed.
2. What is “voting irregularities”? A user got banned because of this. See the first few comments of [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34941/what-should-one-do-if-one-thinks-that-someone-is-mass-voting-them).

Comment: You're probably not seeing the question because it's on page 2 of the bountied questions list. There's a place to click next page at the bottom.

Comment: Regarding voting irregularities, it has to do with things like targeted voting, sockpuppet accounts, etc. The phrasing is deliberately non-specific, though, as we for privacy reasons do not give out details related to suspensions publicly. There's a help center page with some exposition related to voting problems [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).

Comment: See [this previous Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33200/3111) about viewing the active bounties you have on your Activity page (as also the Earned and Awarded bounties).

Comment: There are two places where you can view bounties - one of them only shows 48 questions. More details about this can be found here: [Bountied question didn't pop up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34164).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472522/1072645) that you put a bounty on can be seen in the "Bountied questions" list. Since it’s only recently been bountied, it’s at the bottom of the list ($3$rd last question).
2. Voting irregularities refers to voting in bad faith, which includes targeted voting and voting posts of [sockpuppet accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet_account).